# First value is missing in excel file in XLSX JS

Tags: javascript, excel, file, xlsx

I am trying to read excel file in Javascript with the plugin xlsx.js . I can read all cell values except the first value. Here is my code:

> let numArr = [];
>
> selectFile(event) {
>       let reader = new FileReader();
>
> ```
> reader.onload = () => {
>   const data = reader.result;      
>   const workbook = XLSX.read(data, {
>     type: 'binary'
>   });      
>
>   workbook.SheetNames.forEach((sheetName) => {
>     // Here is your object
>     const XL_row_object = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(workbook.Sheets[sheetName]);
>     // var json_object = JSON.stringify(XL_row_object);
>
>     for (let i = 0; i < XL_row_object.length; i++) {
>       // this.groupNumsArr.push(XL_row_object[i]['number']);   
>       const theNum = Object.values(XL_row_object[i])[0].toString();    
>       numArr.push(theNum);
>     }
>   });
> };
> reader.readAsBinaryString(event.target.files[0]); }
> ```

Answer (score 1):

The api gives first row as key so You can try this

```
for (let i = 0; i < XL_row_object.length; i++) {

        var theNum = '';
        if(i == 0)
        {
           theNum = Object.keys(XL_row_object[i])[0].toString(); 
           numArr.push(theNum);
        }
      // this.groupNumsArr.push(XL_row_object[i]['number']);   
       theNum = Object.values(XL_row_object[i])[0].toString();    
      numArr.push(theNum);

    }
```